# Delay action in swift/Xcode when (answer) button pressed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a quiz app for ios 10 that I have developed but I am fairly new to coding.

In the app the questions are cycled through, you select an answer, then a colour is displayed on the correct answer button and to get to the next question you have to hit another button. 
I would like the next question to appear automatically after 1 second of pressing the previous answer. How do I go about doing this?

Here is my current code

```
func answerButtonHandler(_ sender: RoundedButton) {
    timer.invalidate()
    if sender.titleLabel?.text == currentQuestion.correctAnswer {
        score += 1
        questionLabel.text = currentQuestion.correctAnswer
        questionButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        sender.backgroundColor = flatRed
        questionLabel.text = currentQuestion.correctAnswer
        questionButton.isEnabled = true

    }
    for button in answerButtons {
        button.isEnabled = false
        if button.titleLabel?.text == currentQuestion.correctAnswer {
            button.backgroundColor = flatGreen
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks you in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: You can use a Timer/NSTimer that kicks off a block of code whenever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(
           timeInterval: 1.0,
           target: self,
           selector: #selector(myFunc),
           userInfo: ["callback" : onSuccess],
           repeats: false)
```

And next time to a search before asking....

Comment: Thank you for your help. After some more digging I managed to get your code working within my code. I did search for over an hour and on this site there was only one other post i saw which I couldn't get working.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

This can do using **Grand Central Dispatch** in IOS using following code :

**Swift 3**

```
let delay : Double = 1.0 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay) {

    // in here you can perform a code with delay

}
```

**Swift 2**

```
let seconds = 1.0
let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

   // in here you can perform a code with delay

})
```

You can learn more with [this](https://www.appcoda.com/grand-central-dispatch/).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I couldn't get this working (wasn't sure where to input it properly) but I managed it with one of the other response. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a timer for 10 seconds for example:

```
var counter = 10

var _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.75, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func updateCounter () {
   if counter > 0 {
     counter -= 1
   } else {
        //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I couldn't get this working (wasn't sure where to input it properly) but I managed it with one of the other response. Thank you